# Unrealistically high AUC-ROC score comparing to control feature and other performance measures

Tags: predictive-models, scikit-learn, model-evaluation, roc, auc

I am making a binary classification using regularized logistic regression, with extreme unbalanced data. The target label is `Tar` and non-target label is `non-Tar`.

I am using both the `dummy` feature (which is just random value with no prediction power) against the `full feature set` (which should have some predictive power). However, I also did a subsampling so that it didn't allow the machine learning algorithms to learn much, so that I can compare the results between the `dummy` and `full feature set`.

I am also testing it on both test dataset and external dataset (which is not used for training, but a completely new dataset which the prediction can apply).

Here are the results:

```
>>>> On test data <<<<
>> Feature = dummy

>> Class label count, in test set:
 non-Tar    9915
Tar           9
Name: VAR_RECAT_VFINAL, dtype: int64 

>> Class label count, predicted:
 non-Tar    9924
dtype: int64 

>> Classification report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Tar       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
      non-Tar       1.00      1.00      1.00      9915

    accuracy                           1.00      9924
   macro avg       0.50      0.50      0.50      9924
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      9924


>> Custom classification report:
 ('Accuracy:', 0.999, 'Sensitivity:', 0.0, 'Specificity:', 1.0, 'PPV:', nan, 'NPV:', 0.999, 'F1-score:', nan) 

>> Custom scores:
 ('ROC_v0:', 0.442, 'ROC:', 0.442) 

//////////////////////
//////////////////////

>>>> On external data <<<<
>> Feature = dummy

>> Class label count, in external test set:
 non-Tar    11
Tar         1
Name: VAR_RECAT_VFINAL, dtype: int64 

>> Class label count, predicted:
 non-Tar    12
dtype: int64 

>> Classification report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Tar       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      non-Tar       0.92      1.00      0.96        11

    accuracy                           0.92        12
   macro avg       0.46      0.50      0.48        12
weighted avg       0.84      0.92      0.88        12

>> Custom classification report:
 ('Accuracy:', 0.917, 'Sensitivity:', 0.0, 'Specificity:', 1.0, 'PPV:', nan, 'NPV:', 0.917, 'F1-score:', nan) 

>> Custom scores:
 ('ROC_v0:', 0.409, 'ROC:', 0.409) 

//////////////////////
//////////////////////

>>>> On test data <<<<
>> Feature = full feature set

>> Class label count, in test set:
 non-Tar    9915
Tar           9
Name: VAR_RECAT_VFINAL, dtype: int64 

>> Class label count, predicted:
 non-Tar    9924
dtype: int64 

>> Classification report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Tar       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
      non-Tar       1.00      1.00      1.00      9915

    accuracy                           1.00      9924
   macro avg       0.50      0.50      0.50      9924
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      9924


>> Custom classification report:
 ('Accuracy:', 0.999, 'Sensitivity:', 0.0, 'Specificity:', 1.0, 'PPV:', nan, 'NPV:', 0.999, 'F1-score:', nan) 

>> Custom scores:
 ('ROC_v0:', 0.963, 'ROC:', 0.963) 

//////////////////////
//////////////////////

>>>> On external data <<<<
>> Feature = full feature set

>> Class label count, in external test set:
 non-Tar    11
Tar         1
Name: VAR_RECAT_VFINAL, dtype: int64 

>> Class label count, predicted:
 non-Tar    12
dtype: int64 

>> Classification report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Tar       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      non-Tar       0.92      1.00      0.96        11

    accuracy                           0.92        12
   macro avg       0.46      0.50      0.48        12
weighted avg       0.84      0.92      0.88        12

>> Custom classification report:
 ('Accuracy:', 0.917, 'Sensitivity:', 0.0, 'Specificity:', 1.0, 'PPV:', nan, 'NPV:', 0.917, 'F1-score:', nan) 

>> Custom scores:
 ('ROC_v0:', 0.727, 'ROC:', 0.727)
```

All the performance measures (accuracy, precision, recall, F1, etc) seem reasonable for models expected to not able to learn much.

The AUC-ROC scores seem reasonable in the `dummy` feature sets, to be around 0.442 and 0.409 which is close to the 0.5 mark of random guessing.

However, I got unbelievably high AUC-ROC scores (0.963 and 0.727) from the `full feature set`, which made the same predictions and obtained the same scores (all but AUC-ROC score) as the `dummy` set.

Here are the Python code snippets:

```
def custom_classification_report(y_true, y_pred):
    tp, fn, fp, tn = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    acc = (tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn)
    sen = (tp)/(tp+fn)
    sp = (tn)/(tn+fp)
    ppv = (tp)/(tp+fp)
    npv = (tn)/(tn+fn)
    f1 = 2*(sen*ppv)/(sen+ppv)
    return ('Accuracy:', round(acc, 3),
        'Sensitivity:', round(sen, 3),
        'Specificity:', round(sp, 3),
        'PPV:', round(ppv, 3),
        'NPV:', round(npv, 3),
        'F1-score:', round(f1, 3)
        )

def custom_scores(y_true, y_pred_score, target_name):
    false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(
        y_true, y_pred_score, pos_label='non-'+target_name)
    roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
    return ('ROC_v0:', round(roc_auc, 3) 
            , 'ROC:', round(roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_score), 3))

pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor, control_panel['ml_algo'][1]['clf'])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
target_labels = [control_panel['binary_target_label'], 
    'non-{}'.format(control_panel['binary_target_label'])]
predicted_labels = pipe.predict(X_test)
predicted_scores = pipe.decision_function(X_test)

print('>> Custom classification report:', custom_classification_report(y_test, predicted_labels))
print('>> Custom scores:', custom_scores(y_test, predicted_scores, target_labels[0]))
```

Is it likely a real phenomenon? Or is it more likely this was due to a code error? How can I further test it?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a different Train-test split. 10 test instances is not a lot. An AUC that is based on predictions that differ in very few switches in ranking order might end up giving you inaccurate performance estimations.

Comment: I haven't checked your code. Before you do that, just increase test size and reevaluate.